# Swagger-ui "try it out" doesn't work with body

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I've added swagger-ui to my project with documentation via `.yaml` file. When I'm trying to call "Try it out" for `POST` request with `body` I'm getting next error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…) Operation.execute 
@ dumper.js:499submitOperation 
@ index.js:164r 
@ lodash.min.js:26dispatch 
@ jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2h 
@ jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
```

`POST` without `body` works as expected.

Does anyone know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Just missed name parameter for body.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2500